# How do I use Path.DirectorySeparatorChar in C++/CLI project

Tags: c++-cli

I am building a very simple C++/CLI project and ran into a fundamental problem.

I don't know how to include "references" so system objects will resolve.

for example the c# system object "Path" is undefined... what do I need to add to allow me to use .net objects?

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall IsIPValid(const wchar_t* Param1)
{
    DateTime now;

    String^ test = gcnew String(Param1);

    String^ sep = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: References are available in project properties however you probably already have it. You're missing the namespace, Path is in System::IO. Add using namespace or use full type name. Also in C++/CLI you access static members with :: then it's System::IO::Path ::DirectorySeparatorChar

Comment: It is not any different from native C++, std::string for example.  Just spell out the full name, System::IO::Path::DirectorySeparatorChar.  You already know how to use the using namespace statement to make the name shorter.

Comment: ahhh... scope resolution operator ... thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the scope resolution operator:

```
Path::DirectorySeparatorChar->ToString();
```